# Is it possible to use fluid model for behaviour of non thermal/cold plasma

Tags: plasma-physics

I need to study the impact of magnetic field on dielectric barrier discharge plasma in plasma actuator configuration. 
But i have read that the velocity distribution is non maxwellian so i am a little confused.

Comment: Do you mean nonthermal AND cold, or nonthermal OR cold? They aren't necessarily interchangeable. Unless your definition of "nonthermal" is different than I assume it is (and I assume that nonthermal means not in thermal equilibrium).

Comment: You can but the real question is whether that fluid model will yield anything meaningful or realistic.  If your collision rates are high, you might get better results than you would, say, in the solar wind.  However, you would need to be extremely careful with closure (i.e., chose your equation of state wisely and how you close the velocity moments).